# Grails - How to update a GSP after changing a select?

Tags: select, grails, instance, gsp

I have written a domain class and scaffolded the controller and the views. I've modified the list.gsp and list action a bit. To filter what's displayed, I've put a g:select tag on the page.

Whenever the value in the select is changed, the list controller is fired again and filters the data instance returned. This works like a charm.

Thing is that I can't display the changed instance; the only way I know to update the GSP is to do a window.location.reload() but that results in a re-initialization of the page. So everything is back to default.

So here is the question: how can I make my GSP pick up the changed instance data and display that?

For example, one of the selects. The returned instance is filtered though the selected month and year variables.

```
        <g:select id="monthSelection" from="${['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrt', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec']}" value="${inputYear}" onchange="${remoteFunction(
        action:'list', 
        params:'\'selectedYear=\' + escape(yearSelection.value) +\'&selectedMonth=\' + escape(this.value)'
        )}"
        "/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you either need to

1. reload the whole page on month selection (passing the selected month as a parameter), or
2. change your `remoteFunction` method so that it returns a template view, and set the `update` parameter on the `remoteFunction` call to specify which div on the page should get dynamically updated with the content from the returned view.

I've used option 2 in several cases where I needed an ajax update and it worked nicely.

Comment: @Robin: I agree that ajax call (option 2) is a more approriate choice, since you use remoteFunction(http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+remoteFunction)

Answer (score 3):

Try out something like this :

```
    <g:select id="monthSelection" from="${['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrt', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec']}" value="${inputYear}" onchange="${remoteFunction(
            action:'list', 
            params:'\'selectedYear=\' + escape(yearSelection.value) +\'&selectedMonth=\' + escape(this.value)',
            update : 'divId'
)}"/>
```

Here 'divId' should contains the html portion that you needs to update after an ajax call with list action.

Like :

```
<div id='divId'>
.....
....
</div>
```